# git submodule update with Access Token inconsistent behavior

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, access-token, git-submodules

#### Context

On a self-managed GitLab instance, with multiple users and groups,
I'm trying to do a `git submodule update --init --recursive` in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` of `main_project`. This repo contains a submodule (`filter_lib`), itself containing a submodule (`helper_funcs`):

```
main_project
├── app
│   └── filter_lib                    <- submodule
│       ├── .gitmodules
│       ├── lib
│       └── helper_funcs              <- submodule
│           └── funcs
├── .gitmodules
├── .gitlab-ci.yml
├── .gi
└── tests
    └── test_stuff.py
```

`main_project` is in one GitLab group (let's call it `group1`) and both submodules (`filter_lib` and `helper_funcs`) are in another GitLab group and subgroup (`group2/subgroupA`), with no acces right to each other:

```
my_gitlab_instance
├── group1
│   └── main_project
└── group2
    └── subgroupA
        ├── filter_lib
        └── helper_funcs
```

#### Problem

I want to `init` all submodules.
First, I tried with this code at the beginning of my `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```yaml
variables:
  GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive
```

This CI failed with the following error before attempting to run my scripts:

```
Updating/initializing submodules recursively with git depth set to 50...
Submodule 'app/filter_lib' (https://gitlab-ci-token:[MASKED]@my_gitlab_instance.com/group2/subgroupA/filter_lib.git) registered for path 'app/filter_lib'
Cloning into '/builds/group1/main_project/app/filter_lib'...
Submodule path 'app/filter_lib': checked out '28d6c0f2d0bc691c29a406f44ae9b69b4e00f2b2'
Submodule 'helper_funcs' (git@gitlab:group2/subgroupA/helper_funcs) registered for path 'app/filter_lib/helper_funcs'
Cloning into '/builds/group1/main_project/app/filter_lib/helper_funcs'...
error: cannot run ssh: No such file or directory
fatal: unable to fork
fatal: clone of 'git@gitlab:group2/subgroupA/helper_funcs' into submodule path '/builds/group1/main_project/app/filter_lib/helper_funcs' failed
Failed to clone 'helper_funcs'. Retry scheduled
Cloning into '/builds/group1/main_project/app/filter_lib/helper_funcs'...
error: cannot run ssh: No such file or directory
fatal: unable to fork
fatal: clone of 'git@gitlab:group2/subgroupA/helper_funcs' into submodule path '/builds/group1/main_project/app/filter_lib/helper_funcs' failed
Failed to clone 'helper_funcs' a second time, aborting
Failed to recurse into submodule path 'app/filter_lib'
```

It is kind of expected because `group1/main_project` doesn’t have read rights to any repo in `group2`.

So I tried another way, by changing the `GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY` to normal and allowing `group1/main_project` to access `group2/subgroupA/filter_lib` and `group2/subgroupA/helper_funcs` the following way:

For `filter_lib`, I went into the repo *Settings > Access Tokens* and generated a token with all available scopes and the `Maintainer` role. I then added this token in *`main_project` > Settings > CI/CD > Variables* as a masked variable named *FILTER_LIB_CLONE_KEY*.
I did the same for `helper_funcs`, with the variable named *HELPER_FUNCS_CLONE_KEY*.

**Please note all the following commands were executed through the `.gitlab-ci.yml` of `main_project`.**

I then sed the .gitmodules of `main_project` before attempting to `git submodule update`, so that it looked like this during the CI stage:

```sh
$ cat .gitmodules
[submodule "app/filter_lib"]
    path = app/filter_lib
    url = https://gitlab-ci-token:[MASKED(FILTER_LIB_CLONE_KEY)]@my_gitlab_instance.com/group2/subgroupA/filter_lib.git
```

Running `git submodule update --init` in `main_project` successfully cloned the content of `group2/subgroupA/filter_lib`:

```sh
$ cd app/filter_lib
$ ls -al
total 23
drwxrwxrwx    4 root     root          4096 May 17 10:51 .
drwxrwxrwx    3 root     root          4096 May 17 09:24 ..
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root            40 May 17 09:24 .git
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root           137 May 17 10:51 .gitmodules
drwxrwxrwx    2 root     root          4096 May 17 10:52 helper_funcs
drwxrwxrwx    6 root     root          4096 May 17 09:24 lib
```

I did the same for `app/filter_lib/.gitmodules`, which looked like this during the CI after the sed:

```sh
$ cat app/filter_lib/.gitmodules
[submodule "helper_funcs"]
    path = helper_funcs
    url = https://gitlab-ci-token:[MASKED(HELPER_FUNCS_CLONE_KEY)]@my_gitlab_instance.com/group2/subgroupA/helper_funcs.git
    ignore = dirty
```

In `filter_lib`, I then did:

```sh
$ git submodule update
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
fatal: clone of 'git@gitlab:group2/subgroupA/helper_funcs' into submodule path '/builds/group1/main_project/app/filter_lib/helper_funcs' failed
Failed to clone 'helper_funcs'. Retry scheduled
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
fatal: clone of 'git@gitlab:group2/subgroupA/helper_funcs' into submodule path '/builds/group1/main_project/app/filter_lib/helper_funcs' failed
Failed to clone 'helper_funcs' a second time, aborting
```

However, manually cloning the `helper_funcs` repo at the right place with *HELPER_FUNCS_CLONE_KEY* works.

Why is it possible to `git clone` but not to `git submodule update` with the same repo url?

Why does the `git submodule update` works on the first submodule but not on the second, even though access rights are the same?

Comment: The `cannot run ssh` error indicates that this attempt was using ssh, not https; for that to work, ssh must be installed and you must have the ssh keys. The `Host key verification failed.` error indicates that ssh is now installed, but this is probably the first time this ssh instance has ever heard of the host in `git@gitlab`: it translated `gitlab` to an IP address, connected there, and got a host key from that machine, but it has no authority saying that the resulting host key is valid and should be *trusted*. To fix this problem, use `ssh-keyscan` or similar to [continued]

Comment: ... to establish that some particular host (which you're *implicitly trusting* at this point) are who they claim they are. ssh will record this information in `.ssh/known_hosts` and if the same key comes back later, will trust that this is the same host. Note that **none of these are using https** and therefore **none of these methods use authentication tokens**. To use authentication tokens, you must use an `https` URL, not an ssh one.

Comment: Note further that when using any CI system, GitLab or otherwise, the CI system itself does the first `git clone` using ssh or https (depending on the URL). This system could perhaps do the submodule cloning as well using the `--recurse-submodules` option *to* `git clone`, which might sidestep the entire issue, though the URLs for each submodule are in a file `.gitmodules` and the URLs will control whether ssh or https is to be used.

Comment: You'll need a GitLab expert (and/or the GitLab documentation) to tell you how to make GitLab do this, if GitLab can do this at all. I know how to work with Git but GitLab is an add-on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@torek](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72289145/git-submodule-update-with-access-token-inconsistent-behavior#comment127724261_72289145) tells in the comments, git is still using an authentication via ssh and not https as you want.

I had the same problem. In my case, I was installing `openssh` inside my job. Not installing `openssh` was the way to go for git to start using https.

More precisely, my install command went from:

```bash
    - apk add gcc linux-headers musl-dev git openssh
```

to

```bash
    - apk add gcc linux-headers musl-dev git
```

---

Still, I am not sure as to why git uses the ssh method over the https one when `openssh` is installed.